# VoiceOver does not read when aria-pressed changes

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I've noticed that VoiceOver (not sure about other screen readers) does not read that `aria-pressed` has changed when toggling `aria-pressed` on a button via JavaScript. It only gets read out initially when the button receives focus (e.g. "Lorem ipsum, toggle button" when `aria-pressed` is `false` and "Lorem ipsum, selected, toggle button" when `aria-pressed` is `true`).

Can anyone tell me why this is? Is it a bug? Personally, I think that if a user is toggling the state of the button, it makes sense they get notified when it changes state.

Note: Same behaviour with `aria-expanded`.

---

Here's a code snippet to reproduce (assuming VO is turned on).

1. Shift focus to the button.
   VO will read out the state at that time ("Lorem ipsum, toggle button" or "Lorem ipsum, selected, toggle button").
2. Press Return/Space to toggle `aria-pressed`.
3. VO does not read anything. Why? (You can see that the `aria-pressed` value has changed if you inspect the DOM.)

```js
function toggleAriaPressed(event) {
  var $element = $(event.target);
  var pressed = $element.attr('aria-pressed') === 'true';
  $element.attr('aria-pressed', !pressed);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="toggleAriaPressed(event)" aria-pressed="false">Lorem ipsum</button>

<span tabindex="0">Something else focusable</span>
```